# Remove only the last hash of the URL, which was added with window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash, window.location

I have a problem with a modal box, which when opened adds a hash to the current url (which may have other hashes)

### 01

This code works fine for me but leaves this **"#"** when the hash is removed

```
window.location.hash = location.hash.replace(/#About/, '');
```

**example**
**when the modal opens:**
www.mywebsite.com/#products#About

**when the modal is closed:**
www.mywebsite.com/#products#

**what I want to get:**
www.mywebsite.com/#products

---

### 02

Also try this one that works fine but eliminates all previous hashes

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

or

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

**the results:**

**when the modal opens:**
www.mywebsite.com/#products#About

**when the modal close:**
www.mywebsite.com  (I do not want the previous hashes removed)

---

**This is my code:**

```
$(".barMenuFooter a.buttonShowDetail").on('click', function(){  
$(this).toggleClass('active');
if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    window.location.hash = location.hash + "#About";
    openAbout();    
}
 else {
    window.location.hash = location.hash.replace(/#About/, '');
    closeAbout();   
   } 
 });
```

I just want to completely remove the last hash added (without the #) without reloading the page.

Comment: try `window.location.hash = window.location.hash.split('#').slice(0,-1).join('#')`. see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regexp to find the last "hash" in your url:

```
 > "site.com/#place1/#place2".replace(/\#$|\#[A-z0-9]*$/, "")
 'site.com/#place1/'

 > "site.com/#place1#".replace(/\#$|\#[A-z0-9]*$/, "")
 'site.com/#place1'

 > "site.com/#place1/#".replace(/\#$|\#[A-z0-9]*$/, "")
 'site.com/#place1/'
```

`/\#$/` This will match the last hash(#) that appears in the end of the string (url).

`/\#[A-z0-9]*$/` This will match the last hash(#) that appears in the end of the string(url) with any characters or numbers after it.

Comment: Note that `[A-z0-9]` is not a good way of matching `[A-Za-z0-9]` as it includes a number of punctuation characters in the decimal range 91..96 under ASCII rules; it is even less advisable in EBCDIC, though that isn't likely to be an issue for you.